# Laravel and MySQL Group Replication

Tags: mysql, laravel, high-availability, mysql-group-replication

I'm trying to create a Laravel app with a HA MySQL setup.
So I landed on MySQL Group Replication with three servers in Multi-Primary mode and a Load Balancer in front of the MySQL servers.

This worked out pretty well until I found out that MySQL Group Replication couldn't handle cascade statements in my Laravel app. The only way this could be fixed was changing from a Multi-Primary setup to a Single-Primary setup with the rest of the servers as slaves.

In MySQL Group Replication if the master goes down, it will automatically appoint one of the slaves as the new master. But I can't figure out how to handle this in my app. The best I can figure out is manually changing the MySQL server IP in Laravel if the master goes down. I can't use the Load Balancer setup any longer as only the master can accept writes.

Does anyone know of a way I can handle the automatic changing of MySQL servers in Laravel? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

My answers might come a bit too late but i will be answering from my personal experience anyway in case someone else stumbled upon this thread.

You can take a look at mysql router
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-router/8.0/en/

Basically, the one that i have setup is that each of my application server was installed with mysql router and my laravel was configured to use the socket from the local mysql router. Mysql router have the features to detect which master fail and automatically redirect the write/read to the other available nodes